# Why does Perkins leave and meet Winston?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, john-wick

When John Wick arrives at Marcus’ home, we see that Perkins was waiting for him outside, presumably to kill him. But then she gets a phone call and … *leaves*.

> It was Winston who called, and he gets her killed at their meeting place.

**Why did Perkins meet with Winston (instead of fleeing from him)?**

It should be pretty clear to Perkins that she is disgraced for breaking the rules in the Continental, and when Winston (the owner) calls her to meet at some unpopulated place, she can’t really expect a friendly talk. So why does she meet with him in the first place? It can’t be her sense of honour after willfully breaking such a well-known rule.

And even *if* she has a good reason to meet him, why would she leave immediately instead of sparing a few minutes for trying to kill John?

Comment: I'll have to rewatch this.  I remember when I saw it, that it wasn't really specified what the punishment was for breaking the hotel rules.  I also got a sense that Winston was more than just a hotel manager; it appeared that he had some clout.  My first guess is that it was just a way to show the audience what happens when you break the rules.

Answer (score 8):

I saw the scene and wondered the same question. My best rationale is that: if you get a phone call from Winston asking you to show up, *you don't question, you drop whatever you are doing and you show up!*

Even in the grandiose world of big hitting rich assassins, Winston is a really big shot: he is extremely wealthy (a hotel owner whose apologizing gesture meant a buying you a fancy car), powerful (has many lethal underlings and captures great respect from those around him) and can create rules where there would otherwise be chaos.

Answer (score 1):

She doesn't kill John because the contract was pulled, so she would break another rule and not even get payed for the kill.

The movie is unclear what happens if someone breaks the "no killing in the hotel", it just states that there are "heavy punishments" on breaking it.

In the movie everybody except Perkins obeys the rule and it is probably not very common for a hotel guest to have a price on his head. Taking this into account it seems that the "heavy punishment" isn't used often and probably she didn't know what it ment.
Also we don't know what Winston said during the phone call, so he could have used a lie.

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe there is "nowhere to run" if anyone breakes the rules of Continental, or at least the way Perkins accepts her fate tries to show it to the audience.